# How to apply FBX animation on a rigged character?

Tags: animation, .fbx

I bought an animation pack (GunFu Pistol Attacks) and I only got weird point cloud fbx files and not an actual rig/skeleton.

How can I apply this animation on a rigged character in blender?
Currently the rigged character has a different skeleton than the fbx file.
[image]